# Delete RAID 1 from Debian

Tags: linux, debian, raid, raid1

i've Debian installed RAID 1 2x 160GB HD, i want to delete it but i'm totally noob in linux, i don't want to install fresh image and start from scratch again, i cannot do backup because i've nearly 140GB already used.

Comment: This is software raid using mdadm? or hardware raid?

Comment: @stew Software RAID 1

Comment: As I understand your question, you are asking how to untie a software raid 1 so you have both disks available. Is that correct?

Comment: yes @Posipiet they're available

Comment: So you have no backup?  I would wor k on that first...

Comment: @Zoredache i don't know how to take backup

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways your system can be setup to boot, but a common method using mdadm is to boot read-only from a single device, then remount the root read-write as the raid pair.

It is most likely that editing your /etc/fstab to repoint /dev/mdadm* to /dev/hda* will break the pair. After that, /dev/hdb* will be a backup of where you were when you rebooted. You can obliterate and use as you wish.

Keep in mind that there are many ways in Linux to create a software raid pair, so measure thrice then cut. LVM is different than mdadm, etc.

Comment: i still cannot figure out how to do it, but i've checked i've mdadm in  the server